# Does statement 1 imply statement 2?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

1)  (For some $t, P(t).) \implies Q$.

2)  For all $t, (P(t) \implies Q).$

I think so, and my reasoning is this: for Q to be true, we just need P to be true for some t. Therefore, over the range of all possible t's, once P is true, Q is immediately true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

(1) "*If* (there exists a $t$ such that $P(t)$ holds) then *Q*."

IMPLIES

(2) "For *any* t, (*if* $P(t)$ holds *then* also $Q$ holds)."

This is because we are ensured in the first proposition that, *from* the existence of *any* $t$ such that $P(t)$, *it follows* that $Q$. And this amounts to saying, $\forall t( P(t) \rightarrow Q)$.

Answer (score 2):

Remember that $0 \implies Q$.

First statement says that, either $\forall t \neg P(t)$ (that is, $\neg \exists t P(t)$) or $1 \implies Q$. This is enough to satisfy second statement.

Comment: Thanks, but the missing key step ("This is enough to satisfy second statement."-- why?) is precisely the formal proof that could justify my informal argument.

Comment: What if I wrote $\forall t \neg P(t)$ as $P(t) = 0$? The statement is that either $1 \implies Q$ or $1$ never occurs. I don't think it's missing anything...

Answer (score 1):

In cases like this I try to avoid informal reasoning, and just use the laws of predicate logic, and calculate:
\begin{align}
& \langle \exists t :: P(t) \rangle \implies Q \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"expand $\;\implies\;$"} \\
& \lnot \langle \exists t :: P(t) \rangle \lor Q \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"DeMorgan on left hand side -- the simplest way to introduce $\;\forall\;$"} \\
& \langle \forall t :: \lnot P(t) \rangle \lor Q \\
(*)\;\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"pull $\;Q\;$, which does not depend on $\;t\;$, inside of $\;\forall t\;$ -- as in our goal"} \\
& \langle \forall t :: \lnot P(t) \lor Q \rangle \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"reintroduce $\;\implies\;$"} \\
& \langle \forall t :: P(t) \implies Q \rangle \\
\end{align}
This shows that not only 1) implies 2), but also the other way around.

The key step here is $(*)$, which is a well-known law in predicate logic; its proof depends on the particular formalism one uses.

Note that I (for the most part) use notations from [EWD1300](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/EWD/transcriptions/EWD13xx/EWD1300.html).  In particular, putting quantifiers inside the brackets, so writing $\;\langle \exists x :: \dots \rangle\;$ instead of $\;(\exists x)(\dots)\;$, makes things clearer for me.  Otherwise I might be tempted to misread $\;(\exists x) (P) \implies Q\;$ as $\;(\exists x)(P \implies Q)\;$.  Putting the brackets on the outside avoids the need to define the precedence of quantifiers.